# Automapper map nested different object properties

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I have the following `Company` and its nested object `CompanyEmployee`:

```
public class Company
{ 
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string LogoPath { get; set; }
    public string RammeId { get; set; }
    public List<CompanyEmployee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyEmployee
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to map the Entities to Dtos defined as the following objects `CompanyDto` and its nested object `EmployeeDto`:

```
public class CompanyDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LogoPath { get; set; }
    public string RammeId { get; set; }
    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeDto> Employees { get; set; }
}   

public class EmployeeDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public List<RoleDto> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is the `CompanyEmployee` to `EmployeeDto` mapping.

How can I create a map that can take the property `EmployeeId` and map it to the `Id` property of `EmployeeDto`?

Currently, I have the following maps:

```
    CreateMap<EmployeeDto, CompanyEmployee>(MemberList.Destination)
        .ForMember(emp => emp.EmployeeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(ce => ce.Id));

    CreateMap<CompanyDto, Company>(MemberList.Destination)
        .ForMember(c => c.Employees.Select(e => e.CompanyId), opt => opt.MapFrom(cd => cd.Id));

    CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>(MemberList.Destination)
        .ForMember(c => c.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(cd => cd.Employees.First().CompanyId));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create an AutoMapper Profile to configure each property mapping.
Create classes that inherit from Profile and put the configuration in the constructor.

For example:

```
public class EmployeeProfile : Profile
    {
        //Constructor
        public EmployeeProfile()
        {
            //Mapping properties from CompanyEmployee to EmployeeDto
            CreateMap<CompanyEmployee, EmployeeDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EmployeeId));

            //Mapping properties from EmployeeDto to CompanyEmployee 
            CreateMap<EmployeeDto, CompanyEmployee>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EmployeeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
        }
    }
    public class CompanyProfile : Profile
    {
        //Constructor
        public CompanyProfile()
        {
            //Mapping properties from Company to CompanyDto
            CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Employees, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Employees));

            //Mapping properties from CompanyDto to Company 
            CreateMap<CompanyDto, Company>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Employees, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Employees))
            //Setting CompanyId
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => {
                foreach (var employee in dest.Employees)
                {
                    employee.CompanyId = dest.Id;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

[AutoMapper Profile Configuration Documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances)

Comment: But isnt the mapping from Company to CompanyDto missing the CompanyId on all the Employees?

Comment: `ReverseMap` can reverse that `MapFrom` so it's needed only on the initial map.

Comment: @Anonymous The Employee class you provided has a CompanyId property that should be set when you retrieve the entity it from the Database. The EmployeeDto class you provided does not has a CompanyId property so you only need to set the CompanyId going from CompanyDto to Company, which happens on the AfterMap call.

Comment: @elite_developer You are correct. Thanks for the explanation and answer

Answer (score 1):

Just create `Profile` and all properties which have the same name will mapped automatically. However, properties which do not have the same names, they should have custom mapping:

```
public class FromModelToDto : Profile
{
    public FromModelToDto ()
    {
        CreateMap<CompanyEmployee, EmployeeDto>()
            .ForMember(dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(model => model.EmployeeId))
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want to map from Dto to Model, then you should create another mapping class:

```
public class FromDtoToModel : Profile
{
    public FromDtoToModel ()
    {
        CreateMap<EmployeeDto, CompanyEmployee>()
            .ForMember(dest.EmployeeId, opts => opts.MapFrom(model => model.Id))
    }
}
```

[You can read more about `Automapper` here.](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/23/using-automapper-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Alright, so I should rename the Id property of EmployeeDto?

Comment: Ok thanks. But what about the reverse map? I don't see how I can map the CompanyDto Id to the ForeignKey CompanyId in CompanyEmployee?

Comment: @Anonymous If your properties is not mapped, then you should write custom mapping

Comment: Please see updated question. Would that also work for the property Id in CompanyDto and the property CompanyId in List<CompanyEmployee>?

Comment: @Anonymous I don't have a chance to test it, however as far as I remember it should work. Just try to do it.

Comment: @Anonymous I am glad that it helped to you:)